# Continuous functions with product equal to zero

Tags: functions, continuity

Let $f$ and $g$ be two continuous fonctions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ that are not identically equal to zero, and such that $f.g=0.$
Prove that there exist a real number : $a$, such that $f(a)=g(a)=0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By continuity, the sets $f^{-1}(0)$ and $g^{-1}(0)$ are closed.

Moreover, these sets are strictly contained in $\mathbb{R}$ because $f$ and $g$ are not identically equal to zero.

The condition $f(x)g(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ means that
$f^{-1}(0)\cup g^{-1}(0)=\mathbb{R}$.

If by contradiction such $a$ does not exist then $f^{-1}(0)\cap g^{-1}(0)=\emptyset$.

Now $\mathbb{R}$ is connected and therefore it cannot be divided into two disjoint non-empty closed sets.

Comment: About the last line: I know it to be true but can you give a small hint on how to prove it?

Comment: @Piotr Benedysiuk You need a proof that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected. That is if $X\subset\mathbb{R}$ is nonempty, open and closed then $X=\mathbb{R}$. See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751886/if-a-nonempty-set-of-real-numbers-is-open-and-closed-is-it-mathbbr-why-wh

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly longer proof than Robert's that is stated in terms of results from analysis.

Let $\tilde{f}:=|f|$ and $\tilde{g}:=|g|$. They are continuous real-valued functions and satisfy $\tilde{f}\cdot \tilde{g} = 0$. Now let $h = \tilde{f} - \tilde{g}$, which again is continuous. We only have to show that there is some point $x\in \mathbb{R}$ where $h(x) = 0$, for then $\tilde{f}(x) = \tilde{g}(x)$, and we know that $\tilde{f}(x) = 0$ or $\tilde{g}(x)=0$.

Take any point $a \in \mathbb{R}$. If $h(a) = 0$, then we are done. Otherwise, assume $h(a) > 0$. Then $\tilde{f}(a) > 0$ and $\tilde{g}(a) = 0$. Since $\tilde{g}$ is not identically zero, there exists a point $b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\tilde{g}(b) > 0$, and then necessarily $\tilde{f}(b)=0$.
Then $h(b) < 0$ and by the intermediate value there exists $c \in (a, b)$ such that $h(c) = 0$. The case when $h(a) < 0$ is similar.

Answer (score 0):

The set $A=\{x: f(x)\ne 0\}$ is open, and not equal to $\mathbb R $ ( otherwise $g(x)=0$ for all $ x $ ), and is not empty. So there exists $a\in \bar A$ \  $A.$ Since $a\not \in A$ we have $f(a)=0.$ We have $g(x)=0$ for all  $a\in  A,$ and $g$ is continuous, and $a\in \bar A,$ so we have $g(a)\in Cl(\{g(x):x\in A\}=Cl\{0\}=\{0\}.$

Remark: To show that $\bar A$  \  $A$ is not empty when $A$ is a non-empty open proper subset of $\mathbb R$ (which is equivalent to showing that $\mathbb R$ is connected): Take any $x\in A.$ Let $B=\{y\geq x: [x,y]\subset A\}.$ Let $C=\{y\leq x:[y,x]\subset A\}.$

Now if $\sup B=\infty$ and $\inf C=-\infty$ then $A=\mathbb R,$ which is false.

If $\sup B=b<\infty$ then (i)... $[x,b)\subset A.$  (I will let you prove this.) and (ii)... $b\in \bar A.$ But if also $b\in A$ then, because $A$ is open , there exists positive $r$ with $(b-r,b+r)\subset A,$ which implies $[x,b+r/2]= [x,b)\cup [b,b+r/2]\subset A$, which implies $b+r/2\in B,$ which is absurd because it implies $b=\sup B\geq b+r/2>b.$  So $b\in \bar A$ \ $A.$

The case $\inf C=c>-\infty$ is handled similarly.

Comment: what do you mean by "Cl" ?

Comment: @jhon96 . $Cl(S)=\bar S$. It is standard notation, and convenient when $S$ is a long expression. And when $S$ is a subset of two spaces $X, Y $we may need to distinguish the closure of $S$ in $X$ from the closure of $S$ in $Y .$ So we write $Cl_X(S)$ and $Cl_Y(S).$