# The only sets in $\mathbb{R}$ which are both open and closed are the empty set and $\mathbb{R}$ itself

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

The question has already been answered over 
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/751886/151611)

but I was wondering if my approach is correct or not.

---

My attempt: Let $S$ be a nonempty proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and furthermore assume $S$ is both open and closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Since $S$ is open, $S$ is the union of countable family of pairwise disjoint open intervals. Let $(a,b) \subset S$ be the one of such pairwise disjoint open interval.

We claim that $S$ does not contain the point $a$. If it were the case that $a\in S$ then $a\in (c,d)$ where $(c,d) \subset S$ is one of open interval from the family of disjoint open interval. Consider the point $x=\frac{a+ \min \{ b , d \} }{2}$. Then $x \in (a,b) \cap (c,d)$. But this is a contradiction to the fact that $(a,b) , (c,d)$ were from the family of pairwise disjoint open intervals. Hence, $a \not\in S$.

But $a$ is an accumulation point of $S$ and since $S$ is closed, it contains all its accumulation points, thus, $a\in S$.

We have that $a\in S$ and $a \not \in S$, a contradiction! We are done.

---

Is this proof correct?

Comment: ok, but does there exist any other cover ?

Comment: ah nice, so $(0, 1)$ should be there always I guess...

Comment: well, the proof seems correct to me. I would like to give my solution:

So, if we have a set $S$ a subset of $R$ and since it is closed, it could not be bounded. Let's suppose $sup(S) = s$. then $S$ contains $s$ since it is closed. However $s$ also should be an internal point of $S$, meaning that there is a neighborhood around $s$ which belongs to $S$, contradicting the fact $s$ was the supremum. Now we have an unbounded set. if some real number $a$ is not in $S$ then we can take a subset of $S$ $(-\inf, a)$ which will have a subset with a supremum, contradicting our assumption.

Comment: If there is no point in this set $S$ and is empty, it satisfies the requirements, otherwise we have the whole $R$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96529/discussion-between-shota-kobakhidze-and-calvin-khor).

Comment: The proof works, but it does require knowing that every open set in $\Bbb R$ is a union of disjoint intervals (you don't need countable for your proof), which requires some proving itself. A variant of shota's proof is to pick some $z\in S$ and let $s = \sup\{x\mid [z,x] \subseteq S\}$. If $s <\infty$, its neighborhoods all intersect both $S$ and its complement, which cannot be if $S$ is clopen. Therefore, $[z, \infty) \subseteq S$. A similar infimum argument shows that $(-\infty, z] \subseteq S$ as well.